# How do I install emerald on KDE Neon

Tags: apt, kde, kde-neon

I recently switched from Arch Linux to KDE Neon, and now when I try to install emerald theme manager it says:

> ```
> E: Unable to locate package emerald
> ```

But the compiz has been installed Successfully.

I tried adding the PPA of Ubuntu to my repository but didn't worked.

Comment: Please tell us more about your distro, I will help you find correct install package then.

Answer (score 0):

As for my research, **[Smaragd](https://store.kde.org/content/show.php/?content=125162)** (Emerald for KDE) should work for you.